# Auto Increment of Document id in Vespa

Tags: vespa

How can I auto increment document id as I am feeding document of same type into vespa after some period of time.?
Should I have to do the increment of doc id manually?
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to replace the document, use the same id.
If not, use a new id. Vespa does not provide a way to generate id's.